# High Speed dynamic Chart for oscilloscope software

Tags: c++, winforms, timer, charts, oscilloscope

I need help to make the oscilloscope software.I already able make a graph using winform chart tool.This app recieving data from usb device and plotting it in chart.I also use a form updater timer control to update the form and taking data from usb and plot it to chart.

```
private: System::Void FormUpdateTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

if(ReadFile(ReadHandleToUSBDevice, &INBuffer, 65, &BytesRead, 0))       //Blocking function, unless an "overlapped" structure is used   
                {
                    //INBuffer[0] is the report ID, which we don't care about.
                    //INBuffer[1] is an echo back of the command (see microcontroller firmware).
                    //INBuffer[2] and INBuffer[3] contains the ADC value (see microcontroller firmware).  
                    if(INBuffer[1] == 0x37)
                    {
                        data=(INBuffer[3] << 8) + INBuffer[2];  
this->chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(k,data);
```

The problem is the form updates every 1 milliseconds.But i need more fast execution of the form  to get the data and plot it very fast.

updateTimer can not take value less then 1 millisecond. So how can I make this app fast executing?
Please  help!

Answer (score 0):

Things faster than 20/30 milliseconds cannot be seen by your eyes, so it makes no real sense to plot them faster (a computer screen is refreshed 25/30 times per seconds for just that same reason)

May be you problem is not plot them often, but plot a visual cue that let the watcher understand there are more data he cannot see.

You have -in fact- to separate the data acquisition task (that must be faster as the phenomena you are observing and measuring) from the data rendering task (that must be slow as the user eyes are, and run in parallel without interrupting the acquisition) and plot the data in a way the user can understand them.

Think a bit how an analog oscilloscope works:

if you watch a 10Khz wave on a 1ms time base, a "trigger" start the scan every time the level of the wave cross a selected value. The san takes 1ms, so 10 periods are drawn. That sole scan is invisible to your eyes that cannot capture it.

You see the image because 30+ scans triggered on the same value, redraw that same path (on different periods) over and over, due to the periodic nature of the wave.

Comment: The scan dots take n seconds to fade, i.e. they fade slowly it isnt refreshed every frame, so, ideally you have to use a graphics card that can read back from it's own buffer and fade out points over time, to simulate the phosphorus light fading in the oscilloscope.

Comment: Well... not really: the fading of the CRT has an exponential decay with a time constant of about 10ms. After 50ms 90% of the light has gone. (If it takes "seconds" it wold be impossible do draw whatever movement!) The image steadyness is due to the continuous repeating of the track. Whatever analog oscilloscope filkers when the time base gets over 0,1 seconds (and shows a moving point more over,with a shade following it). But the problem here is not to emulate the physics, but to let the computer screen to work to its own speed, not the one of the signal.

Comment: i just looked on youtube, in strongly lit zones the phosphorous took at least 250ms to fade, and that is just visible in the video. I mean that, having worked with many pc Oscilloscopes, I find they look very bad with a refresh rate as fast as the screen, therefore the dots need a fade time to look like nice graphics, the benz of osc emulations uses a fade time. I'm abit spoilt because i used Reaktor programs xy scope for a while and it has adjusteable fade time and dots, so it only needs to draw 100-1000 samples per frame and using graphics card echo, you can adjust fade time.

Comment: Perhaps it's a preference of mine that i like the scope with fade times... here's a demonstration, see what you think suits you best. this is difficult to write, i beleive the only way to do it is with video echo??? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2AG96IGR8A